# Extracting dates from string and into a dataframe into a new column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I am trying to extract dates from a set format of MONDAY, JUNE 14, 2021 from a sea of text in a data frame and create a new column for the extracted dates.

For example, the data frame looks like:

| x | title | ii |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xx | aldkla MONDAY, JUNE 14, 2021 slkfdklkdj | lkskjdfkdlskld |
| yy | alksflksd TUESDAY, November, 23, 2020 alfjsldjf | sfdadsf |

And I am trying to create the end product to be:

| x | title | ii | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | aldkla MONDAY, JUNE 14, 2021 slkfdklkdj | lkskjdfkdlskld | 2021-06-14 |
| yy | alksflksd TUESDAY, November, 23, 2020 alfjsldjf | sfdadsf | 2020-11-23 |

Currently, I have been using the library  datefinder  because I found it to be able to convert the str to date the best. However, once I start using it with a dataframe it does work. This is what I put.

```
df = dataframe #the example above 


Date = datefinder.find_dates(df.title)
for match in Date: 
  df["time"] = match
```

Is there a better method? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[dateutil's](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) parser does a good job with kwarg `fussy=True`:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser

s = pd.Series(["aldkla MONDAY, JUNE 14, 2021 slkfdklkdj", "alksflksd TUESDAY, November, 23, 2020 alfjsldjf"])

s.apply(parser.parse, fuzzy=True)

>>>
0   2021-06-14
1   2020-11-23
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.replace` along with `to_datetime`:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["title"].str.replace(r'\b([^\s,]+),? (\d+), (\d{4})\b', r'\1\2\3'), format='%B%d%Y', errors='ignore')
```

One slight potential problem with the above might occur if the days in your text dates are *not* zero left padded.  In that case, more work would be needed to get those dates to parse properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
# method 1
obj = df['title']
Date = pd.to_datetime(obj.str.replace(r'^.*?(\w+)[\s,]+(\d+)[\s,]+(\d{4}).*?$', r'\1-\2-\3'), 
               format='%B-%d-%Y', 
               errors='ignore')

# method 2
import datefinder
Date = df['title'].map(datefinder.find_dates).map(list).str[0]
```